# #1062 - Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1062

So my MySQL database is behaving a little bit wierd. This is my table:

```
Name shares id  price   indvprc
cat   2     4   81      0
goog  4     4   20      20
fb    4     9   20      20
```

I'm getting this #1062 error when I try to insert into the table. So I looked into it further and realized that when I try to insert values into the table, in which the name and shares values are the same, it will return the #1062 error. For example, If i inserted:

```
fb    4      6     20   20
```

It would return an error. But if i changed the shares number to 6, it would run fine. Is it because of one of my columns that could be unique, or is it just something with mysql?

Comment: what is the primary key on your table?  You cannot have duplicate values in a primary key field.  A primary key can also consist of multiple fields so what fields are in your key?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but could your database have formed a relationship between `shares` and `id` ? take a look in phpMyAdmin and see what you can find....

Comment: Most likely you primary key is composed by the columns `Name` and `shares`. That means that the combination of both columns must be unique (in your example, the combination `fb, 4` already exists)

Comment: well in my phpmyadmin I cannot click on the primary key for both name and shares. Does that mean something?

Comment: Show your schema please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to remove `shares` as your `PRIMARY KEY` OR `UNIQUE_KEY`

Comment: What I did was i dropped both `shares` and `name` and readded them with index of index.

Answer (score 9):

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE your-table-name` to see what column *is* your primary key.

Comment: I got this: `CREATE TABLE stocks (
 name varchar(10) NOT N...`

Comment: This should show you what the primary key and what the unique key is.

Answer (score 9):

1. Make sure `PRIMARY KEY` was selected `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
2. Just enable Auto increment by :
    
   **`ALTER TABLE [table name] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`**
3. When you execute the insert command you have to skip this key.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by changing the "lock" property from "shared" to "exclusive":

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `ID` `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '' , LOCK = EXCLUSIVE;
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the exact error message?  #1062 means duplicate entry violating a primary key constraint for a column -- which boils down to the point that you cannot have two of the same values in the column.  The error message should tell you which of your columns is constrained, I'm guessing "shares".

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is not the best of solution but doing the following will solve the problem

Step 1: Take a database dump using the following command

```
mysqldump -u root -p databaseName > databaseName.db
```

find the line

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT="*****" DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Step 2: Change `*******` to max id of your mysql table id. Save this value.

Step 3: again use

```
mysql -u root -p databaseName < databaseName.db
```

In my case i got this error when i added a manual entry to use to enter data into some other table. some how we have to set the value `AUTO_INCREMENT` to max id using mysql command

Comment: I got the error Unrecognized statement type. (near "ENGINE" at position 0)

Answer (score 0):

Repair the database by your domain provider cpanel.

Or see if you didnt merged something in the phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

The DB I was importing had a conflict during the import due to the presence of a column both autoincrement and primary key.

The problem was that in the .sql file the table was chopped into multiple "INSERT INTO" and during the import these queries were executed all together.

**MY SOLUTION** was to deselect the "Run multiple queries in each execution" on Navicat and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix SQLAlchemy commands with Python's Try-Except. SQL will keep trying regardless, and the error will only show later in your program flow.

Answer (score -2):

I had this error from mySQL using DataNucleus and a database created with UTF8 - the error was being caused by this annotation for a primary key:

```
@PrimaryKey
@Unique
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.UUIDSTRING)
protected String id;
```

dropping the table and regenerating it with this fixed it.

```
@PrimaryKey
@Unique
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.UUIDHEX)
protected String id;
```

Comment: Where did you read that he's using Java and Spring?

Comment: @horvoje - The OP, asked over a decade ago,  had the exact same error message that I had. So when I googled it, 5 years ago, I found this SO question and shared my fix should any one else encounter the exact same error.  Thanks for the memory!