# #1062 - duplicate entry '' for key 'primary'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1062

```
Table 1 - leads
column 1 - lead_source_description

Table 2 - leads_cstm
column 2 -referrer_c
```

I am trying to copy values from `table2.column2` to `table1.column1` using the following query

```
INSERT INTO leads (`lead_source_description`)
SELECT `referrer__c`
FROM leads_cstm
```

I know it is quiet a simple task to do and has been asked already . But I am getting the following error.

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: If you want it to overwrite an existing value (although '' might not be great) use `REPLACE INTO` not `INSERT INTO`

Comment: @zero323 Code ticks are meant for code not to get attention of readers. Check [this link](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful)

Comment: @StephLocke It dint not work though it is saying 20k rows affected. I used `
INSERT INTO leads (`lead_source_description`)
SELECT `referrer__c`
FROM leads_cstm
`

Comment: is T1.C1 a primary key? does t2.c2 have multiple empty rows?  [Poss Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638505/1062-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary)

Comment: No T1.C1 is not primary key. I am sure. t2.c2 has multiple empty rows.

Comment: What is you PK column and what are you inserting to it? Are you really trying to update your existing t1.c1 values or insert completely new rows to t1? (Now it seems you are inserting new rows but only into one column. If t1.PK isn't auto increment column inserting will fail.)

Comment: Do you want to keep those empty rows? If not filter them out in the select, but very very much what @ZZ-bb said

Comment: PK is Id in leads table. I am trying to insert values from column t2.c2 to t1.c1 only. There are many other columns in T1.c1.

Comment: Then you want to be updating existing rows?

Comment: Yes. I want to update only the c2 column. Rest of the column I do not wanna touch

Comment: Please add full table structure, with all keys and indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO leads (`lead_source_description`)
SELECT DISTINCT `referrer__c` FROM leads_cstm
```

Comment: Please expand and explain your answer and why you made the changes you did. A code sample on its own does little to help.

Comment: If there exists duplicate entriesin leads_cstm,that can cause problem while inserting to leads. So this query fetches distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Your "leads" table must have a auto increment ID value and you need to insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO leads (SELECT NULL, table1.column1 , '', ....) // all the column of leads table shoudl be inserted
```