# #1062 - Duplicate entry 'actUpdateInterval' for key 'PRIMARY' when exporting live Wordpress mySQL DB and importing to Localhost machine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, compare

This is a first for me.

I'm trying to export a live WordPress DB to restore it to my localhost machine which I have done a ton of time before but today I am getting the following error and don't know where to begin with it or even what I need to delete, if it is a case of a duplicate entry.

```
Error
SQL query:

-- -- Dumping data for table `wp_wfConfig` -- INSERT INTO `wp_wfConfig` (`name`, `val`) VALUES ('actUpdateInterval', 0x32), ('alertEmails', 0x7765626d6173746572406172797374616c696665736369656e63652e636f2e7a61), ('alertOn_adminLogin', 0x31), ('alertOn_block', 0x31), ('alertOn_critical', 0x31), ('alertOn_loginLockout', 0x31), ('alertOn_lostPasswdForm', 0x31), ('alertOn_nonAdminLogin', 0x30), ('alertOn_throttle', 0x30), ('alertOn_warnings', 0x31), ('apiKey', 0x356132373234663433303764353439633335333132633639636165313462633830323137333665353961326163326537613031386162663938326465623063666262393762616466303864396235346234303464363634613861303739306339343361386432636634666536623639623066346238646662656139323365613463343431366430356162666237366264353636653064623365333362316437363331666162643462373830633462623537363831653162666435646364333734), ('autoBlockScanners', 0x30), ('blockedTime', 0x333030), ('blockFakeBots', 0x30), ('currentCronKey', ''), ('debugOn', 0x30), ('deleteTablesOnDeact', [...]

MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry 'actUpdateInterval' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

[Found a great online compare utility that allows me to share the results with anyone, so if someone could have a look at this and let me know if it is safe to delete one of these entries or let me know what I need to do, I would appreciate it.](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=m0joy)

I've looked at a number of solutions [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638505/1062-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary) but I'm a little nervous of deleting something I am not sure I should be deleting.

**EDIT:**

If I [look at the comparison](http://www.diffnow.com/?report=m0joy), it seems that ('actUpdateInterval', 0x32), it the duplicate entry as there are two there with the number 32 which I am assuming is the problem child?

**EDIT**
Upon [more searching](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mysql-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary-o-1844.html) it looks like a problem with the Wordfence plugin.

I have run [table repairs on all the tables](http://php.about.com/od/mysqladministration/qt/repair_mysql.htm) but this has not solved the issue either.

Next, I've duplicated the working online DB. Duplicated the site, logged in and deleted Wordfence in the hope that it deletes the tables for Wordfence too but this has not worked either.

I'm now at a loss as to what to do next? Any thoughts? This is keeping me from working on the project which I need to get done.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough info to diagnose.

Comment: I don't have more than that to give Strawberry...what more can I give than the error message directly from mySQL as well as this file comparison here: http://www.diffnow.com/?report=m0joy ? I am happy to offer it if you let me know what else you need ;)

Comment: This is not the ideal solution by I eventually dropped all the wp_wf... tables and exported it again which has now worked. Messy, very messy as I don't know enough to see what other dependencies there might be but it's worked for now and I can continue on again with work. I would still like to hear a better solution to this...if for anything to help other people who come across this.

Comment: Also, for next time, check out sqlfiddle.

Comment: Thanks Strawberry. I don't know enough about SQL, but have found that I get quicker results with jsFiddle in the past so  I will try there in future.

Comment: So Wordfence is the culprit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evetually dropped all the wp_wf... tables which allowed me to export it from the live DB to the local DB. This is not the best solution but it did work.